# "str is undefined" on findRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I have a problem with model and serializer. I've looked at the documentation and can't find a solution. My app is connected to a django rest api.

Django response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1/",
    "username": "username",
    "email": "xxx@email.com",
    "is_staff": true
}
```

The model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    url : DS.attr('string'),
    username : DS.attr('string'),
    email : DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I've modified the response with a serializer to include "data":

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'id',
    normalizeFindRecordResponse(store, type, payload, id) {
        console.log('payload',payload)
        return {
            data: {
                'id': id,
                'url': payload.url,
                'username': payload.username,
                'email': payload.email,
            }
        } ; 
    }
});
```

The route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findRecord('users', 1);
    }
});
```

Another version of the route same error:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        this.store.findRecord('users', '1').then(function(user){
            console.log('user', user);
        }).catch(function(e){
            console.log('e', e);
        });
    }    
});
```

Finally Ember inspector has the model but all values as undefined and "str is undefined" on console.

[Image of ember inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dYsw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`normalizeFindRecordResponse` is not returning valid JSONAPI format,
The below is the valid format,

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      // ... this article's attributes
    }        
  }
}
```

As you can see, you are missing `type`, `attributes` key.

2.Your model file name should be `user.js` in singular.
3.`this.store.findRecord('users', 1)` - here you need to use singluar form of the model so `this.store.findRecord('user', 1)`
4.In your another attempt you are missing the return statement in model hook.